# Find critical points of the following function $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, hessian-matrix

I tried to find the critical points of the function

$$f(x,y) = x^2y-2xy + \arctan y $$

And I found that is $P(1,0)$, the problem is that the Hessian is null, and I don't know how to procede to determine the nature of that point.
Can you help me ?

**Update:** Thanks you all, and I tried to study the sign of the function, the problem is that I don't know how to proceed , since I have $Δf(x,y)=x^2y-2xy + \arctan y $ and I don't know how to study the sign locally around $1,0$.

Comment: have you used the second derivative test?

Comment: No Sir, our teacher hasn't said nothing about using it, what I am asking is if I can be helped on studying the sign locally around P(1,0) to determine that is actually a saddle point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(1,0)=0$, $f(1,1)<0$ and $f(3,1)>0$, so $(1,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: I get it that is a saddle point, but is there a way to "formally" show it, like studying the sign of the function locally that point?

Comment: If u can show that $f(a,b)-f(a+h,b+k)$ changes sign for two different choices of $(a+h,b+k)$, then $(a,b)$ is saddle point.

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

for your function $f(x,y)$ holds
$$-\infty<f(x,y)<+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally in cases like this you just have to get your hands dirty. We have that f(1,0) = 0. You want to look at what happens when you vary x and y around (1,0), in various ways. If you can convince yourself that the result is universally positive for (x,y) close enough to (1,0) then this point is a minimum, if it's negative then (1,0) is a maximum, and if you can find, arbitrarily close to (1,0), both points that yield positive values and points that yield negative values then (1,0) is a saddle point.

(Of course, the process by which you do this should be informed and thoughtful, not random. You need to carefully consider the structure of the function in question).

Comment: I tried it, but I cannot help myself studying the sign of the function :"(